# How to server static Vue dist folder in express with app.use('someRoute')

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, routes, static

I am serving a dist folder from a vue app (created with create-vue-app). However, it serves well when I am not pointing to some specific route, just use the root route without anything. However, if I specify a sub-route, e.g like `'/static'` , the it does not serve the vue app dist index.html... I get the message in browser:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/css/app.fc1b515e.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
4localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/js/app.6869d12b.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

however, it finds the favicon.ico if I enter it to the path in browser...

sometimes, I also get the  error message that tells me javascript is not enabled (which is wrong)...

This is how I set up my routes:

```
  app.use('/static',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '\\client\\dist')));
```

Comment: Are you using vue-router ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Vue app is referencing assets relative to `/`, like this:

```
/css/app.fc1b515e.css
/js/app.6869d12b.js
```

...but you are serving the assets at `/static`:

```
/static/css/app.fc1b515e.css
/static/js/app.6869d12b.js
```

You can set the **publicPath** configuration option to `/static/` in **vue.config.js**  to ensure that your Vue app references the static assets correctly.

Docs:
https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath

Hope this helps.